# Get data from OpenDap server that requires authentication using R

Tags: r, ncdf4, opendap

I'm trying to get data from an OPeNDAP server using R and the ncdf4 package. However, the nasa eosdis server requires username / password. How can I pass this info using R?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
require(ncdf4)
f1 <- nc_open('https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/TRMM_L3/TRMM_3B42.7/2018/020/3B42.20180120.15.7.HDF')
```

And the error message:

> Error in Rsx_nc4_get_vara_double: NetCDF: Authorization failure syntax
>   error, unexpected WORD_WORD, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or
>   SCAN_ERROR context: HTTP^ Basic: Access denied. Var: nlat  Ndims: 1
>   Start: 0 Count: 400 Error in ncvar_get_inner(d$dimvarid$group_id,
>   d$dimvarid$id, default_missval_ncdf4(),  :    C function
>   R_nc4_get_vara_double returned error

I tried the url https://username:password@disc2.... but that did not work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daniel,

The service you are accessing is using third-party redirection to authenticate users. Therefore the simple way of providing credentials in the URL doesn't work.

You need to create 2 files.

1. A .dodsrc file (a RC file for the netcdf-c library) with the following content

   HTTP.COOKIEFILE=.cookies
   HTTP.NETRC=.netrc
2. A .netrc file, in the location referenced in the .dodsrc, with your credentials:

   machine urs.earthdata.nasa.gov
   login YOURUSERNAMEHERE
   password YOURPASWORDHERE

You can find more details at 
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/md__Users_wfisher_Desktop_v4_86_81-prep_netcdf-c_docs_auth.html

Regards

Antonio

Comment: in fact you still need to approve the EULA in order to download the data. This can be done in https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/app_eula/nasa_gesdisc_data_archive

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, even after defining the credentials and their location

```
ncdf4::nc_open("https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGDE.06/2020/08/3B-DAY-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20200814-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4")
```

still returns

> Error in Rsx_nc4_get_vara_double: NetCDF: Authorization failure

The same happens when using ncdump from a terminal:

```
$ ncdump https://gpm1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/opendap/GPM_L3/GPM_3IMERGDE.06/2020/08/3B-DAY-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20200814-S000000-E235959.V06.nc4
```

returns

> syntax error, unexpected WORD_WORD, expecting SCAN_ATTR or SCAN_DATASET or
> SCAN_ERROR context: HTTP^ Basic: Access denied. NetCDF: Authorization
> failure Location: file
> /build/netcdf-KQb2aQ/netcdf-4.6.0/ncdump/vardata.c; line 473