# Get aggregated data from OPenDAP ncml that requires authentication using R

Tags: r, r-raster, netcdf4, ncdf4, opendap

I'm trying to get TRMM data from NASA OPenDAP server using the `raster` package in R. Initially I had some difficulty regarding authentication, but that issue was [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098781/get-data-from-opendap-server-that-requires-authentication-using-r/).

NASA OPenDAP server publishes TRMM 3B42_daily data as individual files, one for each day and an aggregated annual data (using ncml). So, my problem now is that, using R `raster` package and the authentication files `.dodsrc` and `.netrc` I can download individual NetCDF files but I can't download the aggregated data.

So, this works:

```
library(raster)
single_date_opendap <- 'https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/opendap/TRMM_L3/TRMM_3B42_Daily.7/2002/04/3B42_Daily.20020405.7.nc4'
test <- stack(single_date_opendap, varname = 'precipitation')
```

This doesn't:

```
library(raster)
url_opendap_no_brkt <- 'https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/opendap/ncml/aggregation/TRMM_3B42_Daily.7/TRMM_3B42_daily.7_Aggregation_2001.ncml'
test <- stack(url_opendap_no_brkt, varname = 'precipitation')
```

And gives me the error message:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...) :
An error occurred while creating a virtual connection to the DAP server:
Error while reading the URL: https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/openda
p/ncml/aggregation/TRMM_3B42_Daily.7/TRMM_3B42_daily.7_Aggregation_2001.ncml.
ver.
The OPeNDAP server returned the following message:
Unauthorized: Contact the server administrator.
Error in .rasterObjectFromFile(x, band = band, objecttype = "RasterLayer",
Cannot create a RasterLayer object from this file. (file does not exist)
```

Is it possible to get data from a OPenDAP server that publishes aggregated data?

Comment: have you tried the ncdump command on de shell?

Comment: Ha! ncdump works!! ncdump -c https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/opendap/ncml/aggregation/TRMM_3B42_Daily.7/TRMM_3B42_daily.7_Aggregation_2001.ncml

Answer (score 0):

After some exchange with NASA support and with Antonio's tip, found out that R `raster` package will not work with the aggregated datasets. But `ncdf4::nc_open` is able to handle it. Strange because, from what I understand, `raster` package calls `nc_open` in the background.

Anyway, this works:

```
library(ncdf4)
url_opendap <- 'https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/opendap/ncml/aggregation/TRMM_3B42_Daily.7/TRMM_3B42_daily.7_Aggregation_2001.ncml'
trmm <- nc_open(url_opendap)
```

and this doesn't

```
library(raster)
url_opendap <- 'https://disc2.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov:443/opendap/ncml/aggregation/TRMM_3B42_Daily.7/TRMM_3B42_daily.7_Aggregation_2001.ncml'
trmm <- stack(url_opendap, varname = "precipitation")
```